# Optimized Copying from char * (C++) to byte array (c#)

Tags: c#, c++, optimization, clr

We need to pass image data with a size of 1000 * 1000 *3 bytes from C++ to C#. In C#, I have copied the data with the following code

```
 byte[] testArray = new byte[1000*1000*3];
 Marshal.Copy(data, testArray, 0, 1000*1000*3);
```

The two lines of code takes about 1.2 ms in my machine. `Marshal.Copy` alone takes .27 ms.

How can I optimize the code to reduce the time required to copy the data?

Comment: If 1.2ms is too much for copying 3 million bytes then .NET is not suited for whatever you are doing

Comment: What's your concern with the time taken?

Comment: There are multiple options, but your question is unclear about the conditions that apply. For example: is the native buffer locked? Can you pre-allocate the space in C#? etc.

Comment: Do you have to copy? Does the C# program require read-only access only?

Comment: Byte array can be read only in C#. but we need a byte array

Comment: @Stefan: I can preallocate memory. The performance optimization is required only for Marshal.Copy part.

Comment: Okay, so the `0.27ms` is to much. Hmm... just a question on forehand: how does the `0.27ms` relate to the rest of the processing? Usually the copying is just a small portion of the algorithm. Anyhow, have you tried this one? : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.buffer.memorycopy?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#overloads

Comment: The most obvious way to avoid the cost of memory allocation and copying is to not copy.  The question keeps it very unclear why it is needed at all.  The pinvoke marshaller certainly doesn't require it, the C++ code can directly access a GC-allocated byte[] buffer for example, the marshaller takes care of pinning the array.  Or the other way around, you can use a byte* in C# code to address memory that was allocated in C++ code.  Post more code that makes the context clear.